Why firestore create dynamic index for all userId
return    
          firestore
          .collection('chatrooms')
          .where('participants', arrayContains: userId)
          .where('chatType', isEqualTo: 'friend')
          .where('visibility.$userId.visible', isEqualTo: true)
          .orderBy('lastMessageTime.$userId', descending: true)
          .snapshots()


and now its creating the composite index like this.
 participants Arrays chatType Ascending visibility.8YvAhlkrD6Qzcu3XgXTdJxInghF2.visible Ascending lastMessageTime.8YvAhlkrD6Qzcu3XgXTdJxInghF2 Descending __name__ Descending
i want that this will not happen.

I'm not sure I understand the question/problem. Firestore only auto-creates indexes for single fields. What you're describing is a composite index, so it is not automatically created.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Firestore indeed requires an index on each value of visibility.$userId.visible. If you don't want that, you'll have to come up with a data model that allows you to implement the use-case without such an index.
The simplest option is to use an array-field to track the visibility:
visibleParticipants: ["uid1", "uid2", ...]

And then query it with:
firestore
  .collection('chatrooms')
  .where('visibleParticipants', arrayContains: userId)
  .where('chatType', isEqualTo: 'friend')
  .orderBy('lastMessageTime.$userId', descending: true)

So this no longer filters in participants, as you can only have a single arrayContains condition in a query.
I expect that the visibleParticipants values overlap with the information you already have in the participants field through, so hopefully you can get the necessary documents with this. If not, you'll have to come up with another data model that allows you to meet your requirements within Firestore's query API.

I am using visibility to delete chatroom from my side only, other participant still see chatroom. And I am also marking the deletedAt timestamp so that , when I again enter to this chatroom all old chat not to visible my side.

Can you help me regarding this.

I'm not entirely sure I get the use-case, but it sounds quite involved. I have better experience with storing duplicated data and then reading it with simpler queries. I.e. did you consider storing the chat room (IDs and/or data) for each user in their user document? This may sounds strange if you come from a background in relational databases, but Firestore is a NoSQL database where this is quite common.

If you're new to this, I recommend reading NoSQL data modeling techniques and watching Get to know Cloud Firestore
